# What is this java post increment operator doing?

Tags: java

So there's a piece of an radix sort implemented Java code that reads as below:

```
aux[count[a[i]]++] = a[i];
```

Why use a post increment operator?  Why not *aux[count[a[i]]+1]*? Is the post increment simply to increment the value in count[a[i]] by 1 and store it there?

radixSort.java

```
int N = a.length;
int[] count = new int[R+1];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  count[a[i]+1]++;
for (int r = 0; r < R; r++)
  count[r+1] += count[r];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  aux[count[a[i]]++] = a[i];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  a[i] = aux[i];
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is the post increment simply to increment the value in count[a[i]] by 1 and store it there?

Yes, exactly. There are two side-effects of the statement: one is a modification to an element of `aux`, and the other is a modification to an element in `count`.

Personally I'd avoid writing it like that - I'd probably write:

```
// We don't use i other than to index into a, so use an
// enhanced for loop instead
for (int value : a)
{
    aux[count[value]] = value;
    count[value]++;
}
```

Note that even if the change to `count` weren't required, `aux[count[a[i]]+1]` wouldn't do the same thing - because `aux[count[a[i]]++]` refers to the element in `aux` with index `count[a[i]]`, *before* the increment, because `++` is being used as a post-increment here.

Answer (score 2):

This `aux[count[a[i]]++] = a[i];` means:

first, take `a[i]` value, and use it as index for count. Then that value use as index in `aux` array and place the value of `a[i]` to its place. Then increment the value on position `count[a[i]]` for `1`.

Its like this:

```
aux[count[a[i]]] = a[i];
count[a[i]] = count[a[i]] + 1;
```

but shorter.

You have also this:
`aux[++count[a[i]]] = a[i];`.
This will take value from `count[a[i]]` and first increment for `1` and then use it as index in `aux` array, so now we search it as:

```
count[a[i]] = count[a[i]] + 1;
aux[count[a[i]]] = a[i];
```

As you can see, `aux[count[a[i]]+1]` is not like `aux[count[a[i]]++]`, since it will not store increased value of `a[i]` for 1 in `a[i]`, and it will take index `a[i] + 1` from `aux`, but `aux[count[a[i]]++]` takes index of `a[i]`.

`aux[count[a[i]]+1]` is similar to `aux[++count[a[i]]]` but the difference is you didn't increment the value in `count[a[i]]`.